# How can I edit a Google Macros Script, When the editor becomes unresponsive?

Tags: google-apps-script, ide, responsiveness

I've made a Macros to create filters (just 3 columns' data) on a large (16k rows) data set. This is the 3rd iteration of this Macros I've created using relative references each time.

When I made the 2nd iteration, I ran into the problem of "The starting range row is too small". When I opened the script to look, the page went unresponsive, forcing me to kill the page. After logging out of my secondary google account, I tried again and was able to edit the script.

Now on my 3rd iteration, I've recorded a new Macros using the relative references set (to add on to the filters I've previously created) and have received the same error message regarding the range as before. Upon opening the script to investigate, as soon as I click anywhere on the page (in the textbox, headers, anywhere!) The page goes unresponsive and I'm forced to kill it and start again.

I'm only logged into one google account, and I've tried both Chrome & Firefox and the page crashes on each try.

How can I edit the script? I can't even open the page! Help!!

Comment: To those who are voting to close as "Needs debugging details", 1. OP provided all details that OP is able to provide at the time including testing different browsers. 2. " The shortest code"- impossible as OP can't reach the script editor, which is why OP is here and that is the actual question.  I believe closing this question  would be unjustified.

Answer (score 2):

#### Possible solutions:

- Wait for the page to react for a long time
- Try clearing your browser cache, storage and cookies
- Open in incognito mode, login and view
- If you're using a bound script, make a copy of the script container, else make a copy of the script using [Google drive](https://drive.google.com)
- Check the [dashboard](https://script.google.com) for any pending executions
- Use [clasp](/questions/tagged/clasp)/[google-apps-script-api](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-api) to get a copy in the terminal.
- If all else fails, you may [contact Google](https://support.google.com/drive/gethelp) or create a [public bug report in the issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905)

Comment: OK I've tried all of these but #3 (bound script) and so far still no luck.  Possible to explain this step further?

Comment: @ChrisTecca visit the drive link. Search for your script or containing spreadsheet and make a copy of that file.

Comment: The Script does not exist in my Drive. When I copied the sheet and tried to open, same thing.. everything froze upon one blink of the text-cursor...

Comment: @ChrisTecca  Check executions in the dashboard. If that doesn't work, Maybe wait a few days. While you're waiting, research [tag:clasp] and try `clasp pull`. If all else fails, contact Google and/or create a public bug report.